# Get css transition start from jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, transition

I am currently trying to bind an event on a transition start.
The animation consists on a textarea resizing on focus.

For transition end we know that we have:

```
jQuery(this).bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function() {
});
```

but for transition end, what can i use?

Note: animationstart and animationend won't do in my case.

Comment: There's no event fired when transitions start. The only available event is the "end" event.

Comment: Have you tried to implement my answer? It should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, i've implemented it, it worked like a charm. Just what I was searching for. Thanks allot!

Comment: Don't forget to mark as correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

If the transition starts on textarea focus then why not use:

```
$('textarea').on('focus focusout', function() {
    $('div').html('started');
}).on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function() {
    $('div').html('ended');
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/neYfj/5/ - it fires when the transition starts and also adds a `transitionend` event.